# PHP preg_replace multiple urls to links

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I using this code to change urls to links:

```
<?php
// The Regular Expression filter
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

// The Text you want to filter for urls
$text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com http://www.ynet.co.il";

// Check if there is a url in the text
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {

       // make the urls hyper links
       echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $text);

} else {

       // if no urls in the text just return the text
       echo $text;

}
?>
```

But every link direct to the first link How can I make foreach that will solve it?

Thanks.

Haim

Comment: What do you mean by "URL" and "link"?

Comment: Its mean the I make this text "Hello http://www.google.com" to "Hello <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$reg_exUrl = "...";
$text = "...";
echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="$0" rel="nofollow">$0</a>', $text);
```

Much simpler ;)